# Publishing a Push Notification Application

Tags: ios, ssl, notifications, certificate, publish

I'm publishing an application with Push Notification on a new developer account.

When creating the Certificate do we need the App Store and Ad Hoc? Or do we only need the Apple Push Notification service SSL only?

> App Store and Ad Hoc Sign your iOS app for submission to the App Store
> or for Ad Hoc distribution.
>
> Apple Push Notification service SSL
> (Production) Establish connectivity between your notification server
> and the Apple Push Notification service production environment. A
> separate certificate is required for each app you distribute.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need both of the certificates.

> AppStore and Adhoc certificate is for the apps to be signed under your
>   account.

Without this, you cant create provisioning profiles and submit the apps.

> Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production) is created for each app to communicate with APNS server.

Without this your certificate your server cant communicate with the APNS service and any push you sent will not reach the user device.